# How can I write out multiple numbers in one input line to solve an equation repeatedly?

Tags: python

Basically I want to input 10 q values and their 10 respective cr values and then have it print out 10 k4 values.

I get the error:unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'.

I know this must fundamentally be me not understanding how lists work, but I've been reading up on them via googling and automate the boring stuff and don't really understand.

This must be because the input is a list and the equation is asking for floats?

```
import math

qmax = 11.3
q = input("Enter q values separated by a comma. ").split(',')
cr = input("Enter cr values separated by a comma.").split(',')


for i in q and cr:
    k4 = cr * ((-math.log(1 - ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)))) +
               (0.5 * math.log(1 + ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)) + ((q / qmax) ** (2 / 3)))) +
               (math.sqrt(3) * math.atan(((math.sqrt(3)) * ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))) / (2 + ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))))))

    print(k4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to iterate on both the input arrays, one way of doing so is using `zip`.

Second, you want to perform numeric operation-> you need to transform the element to `float`.

Both changes can be seen in the following:

```
import math

qmax = 11.3
q = input("Enter q values separated by a comma. ").split(',')
cr = input("Enter cr values separated by a comma.").split(',')


for i_q, i_cr in zip(q,cr):
    i_q = float(i_q)
    i_cr = float(i_cr)
    k4 = i_cr * ((-math.log(1 - ((i_q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)))) +
               (0.5 * math.log(1 + ((i_q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)) + ((i_q / qmax) ** (2 / 3)))) +
               (math.sqrt(3) * math.atan(((math.sqrt(3)) * ((i_q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))) / (2 + ((i_q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))))))

    print(k4)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Enter q values separated by a comma. 1,2,3
Enter cr values separated by a comma.1,2,3
1.3680605611830536
3.5350475424910037
6.2401913565748846
```

Comment: A nice detailed explanation! Just one point here, elements of `q` and `cr` don't have to be `int`s. It's better to convert them to `float`s.

Comment: @iamvegan Absolutely correct, now that i look at that again I see that `qmax` is float, edited!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! You just solved in a minute what I've been trying to wrap my head around for a few hours lol.

Comment: Yes I just did this

i_q = float(i_q)
i_cr = float(i_cr)

as the q and cr values I have are not integers. I ran it and it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code here has issues because q is a **list**

```
k4 = cr * ((-math.log(1 - ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)))) +
               (0.5 * math.log(1 + ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3)) + ((q / qmax) ** (2 / 3)))) +
               (math.sqrt(3) * math.atan(((math.sqrt(3)) * ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))) / (2 + ((q / qmax) ** (1 / 3))))))
```

e.g.

**input**: 3,4,5,6 then

```
q = [3,4,5,6] 

q/qmax = [3,4,5,6]/11.3
```

also your loop is wrong since it is moving down q but not moving down cr.

your i refers to cr. do this instead:

```
for i in range(len(q)):
# reference the q with q[i] and the corresponding cr with cr[i]
```